# Windows File Explorer broken after latest update

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, crash, windows-11

I'm not sure where was the right place to ask this. My roommate has a gaming laptop that runs windows 11 as most games don't support 7 anymore and the latest update not only changed the appearance of their file explorer but also broke it. Every time they try to open it it crashes. The background turns blue and all the icons vanish from their start bar for a second then it all comes back. If they try open the same folder again immediately after the File Explorer crashed it opens just fine, but the appearance has changed to look more... modern, I guess? than it did before the update.

The laptop is for video games alone. They have a different one for work and another for everything else. Nothing has been changed or added but the update. They didn't download or install anything. Everything was working well before the update and now after it's broken.

What did Microsoft *do*? How do we get the old look of the File Explorer back and, most importantly, how do we stop it from crashing?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Windows File Explorer crashing like that is a Shell Context error or worse.

The games may not be Windows 11 compliant. Check this.

Otherwise, Windows 11 Updates work fine and Microsoft is not breaking anything that is working properly. I have my own Windows 11 machines fully up to date.

**(1)** Try a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download. Run the download file (need a USB Key). Then run Setup on the USB key to launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(2)** If Repair / Keep Everything does not fix the issue, then the operating system damage is more severe, or, the Windows User Profile is damaged. In either case, back up and reinstall Windows 11.

For reinstalling Windows, you can use Reset.  Start, Settings, Update, Recovery options and Reset.

Comment: I don't think I have a USB Key. Their games are all from Steam and Epic through the respective launchers. And neither came up with any compatibility issues when the games were being installed or when they update. One would think they'd have some sort of warning if there could be such an issue with them. Besides, it wouldn't be the first time a bad Microsoft update messed up people's computers...

Comment: You need to get a USB Key.  Windows 11 Repair uses this method. Most pharmacies or local computer stores carry these.   You can use Windows Reset (Update / Recovery) to reinstall Windows without a USB Key.  I made my answer more clear on this point.

Comment: it wouldn't be the first time a bad Microsoft update messed up people's computers...    ....   I am not away of any recent Windows 11 updates that have gone bad. It is usually software causing the isssue.

Comment: I know one recently has caused issue for some people with a specific graphics card, though that's not this update and not relevant to this laptop. Throughout the history of Windows plenty of updates updates have caused a whole host of problems.

Comment: These are generally Software Vendor issues and normally not Microsoft issues. There could be rare cases either way. But to correct the issue of File Explorer crashing (which I have seen as the result of Shell Context errors) you need to follow my repair steps

Comment: i'm trying to contact Microsoft's technical support